# When taking values from an object, does unshift() change the source object?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

This question sparked when I was setting the base case of the following code:

```
function withoutReverse(str, arrayFor = []){
    arrayFor.unshift(str[0]);
    if (str.length === 1) 
    return arrayFor.join("");
    else return withoutReverse(str.slice(1), arrayFor)  }

  let hola = "hello";  
  withoutReverse(hola);//-->olleh
```

I thought that the base should be `str.length === 0`, cause I assumed that unshift literally took each element from the source object to put it into `arrayFor`. Then, I realized that that was what I was using `slice` for.

I didn't found a conclusive information in mdn. Am I right? `unshift()` doesn't really *take* those values (when stored in an object)? if so, how is that handled in memory?

Thank you

Comment: As you might have tried , unshift doesn't have association with original array, all it does is take an object and puts it in the beginning of the array from where it is called and returns the new array size.when you are using str[0] it is only taking the object from the array str , it's same as adding any other string.   arrayFor.unshift("myobject")

Comment: `unshift()` does not affect the "source object". There's no way it could since Javascript is *pass-by-value*. It's a language feature, not anything specific to `unshift()`, so this is probably why you didn't find any conclusive info on MDN. The way it's handled in memory is that the value found in `str[0]` is copied and passed as the argument to `unshift()`.

Comment: `String` is a primitive type in JS and it is immutable. Try `s = "foo"; s[0] = "b"` and see that `s` is still `"foo"`. `unshift` indeed mutates its receiver, i.e. the object the method is operating on, which is `arrayFor` not `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to the 5th call:

```
console.log(str) // "o"
arrayFor.unshift(str[0]); // str[0] === "o" 
console.log(str.length) // "1" because accessing the property here does not change it.
```

Therefore your exit condition is now true.

For functions in JS:

- numbers/strings/booleans are passed as values
- arrays/objects are passed as references

Extra info about strings:

> Unlike some programming languages (such as C), JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it.

[Source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

> return 'cat'[1] // returns "a"
>
> When using bracket notation for character access, attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties involved are neither 
>    writable nor configurable. (See Object.defineProperty() for more information.)

[Source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)